# Please help me improve this question

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

A question I posted yesterday is currently sitting on two closevotes with two downvotes.

[What does this dialogue mean in The Barefoot Contessa (1954)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/111026/what-does-this-dialogue-mean-in-the-barefoot-contessa-1954)

I'd very much like to know how to improve this question, because I consider it a serious question into which I put some time and effort to make sure it was presented in an informative and thought-out manner. I am not sure I understand what problems downvoters see in this question, but luckily for me the closevotes are accompanied with a reason. The two close voters so far appear to have thought the question "*needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.*"

Well, the question blockquotes a conversation that won't be considered short--8 lines, but it is not a long conversation either in any sense of the word--taking up rough one minute of the entire viewing time. My question asks what two parts of the conversation mean. Granted it is about two focal points of the same conversation, but the two issues are related and connected by the same conversation they are found in. That's why I thought I'd ask them in a single question, allowing me to include more context which in turn should make the question easier to understand and answer. But I'd like your feedback: would it work better if I asked them in two separate questions?

There has been [one comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/111026/what-does-this-dialogue-mean-in-the-barefoot-contessa-1954#comment189586_111026) left under my question so far:

> "seems to suggest he doesn't believe being rich makes a man more attractive" That is not what the line says; read and interpret it correctly and there is no contradiction. The second part is also easily understandable: think of it as him differentiating between "girls" and "women".

This comment instructs me to "read and interpret it correctly". I tried and still didn't get the meaning of the dialogue. It also points to the crux of first issue: indeed I see a contradiction in the first part of the dialogue. But despite knowing it shouldn't be internally contradictory the meaning of the dialogue still eludes me. I am also just as puzzled by the distinction that comment lays out in front of me. Yes, I guess such a distinction would make sense, but how it fits in the context is still beyond me. I requested clarification in the comments but haven't received a reply. Maybe the commenter has been busy or just too cool to bother. Or maybe they are right, the question is too obvious to answer?

Maybe I am just a little slow. Maybe what I am having difficulty with is just too obvious and too basic to people who down voted. Some may see it as a dumb question but I'd put in honest effort into that question in hopes of soliciting a good answer that'd help me understand a dialogue from a classic movie. I don't know how the question'd meet the downvoting guideline "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Stack Exchange is built on a model designed to encourage good questions but also question improvement and positive editing. So I certainly would like to know how to improve my post to make a better question out of it.

Comment: I can see why the two issues, while part of the same conversation, seem a bit disconnected from each other, which might have led people to close-vote it as "too broad". But you're also right that they're part of the same 1 minute dialogue and could fertilize each other. In any case, each of the two questions, while possibly seeming obvious on first sight, is a reasonable question providing opportunity for further insight into the characters and their attitudes. I'll see what the close-voters have to say on their case.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Thanks! Feedback is always helpful. With input from other people hopefully I will find a balance between context and focusedness.